# Why are my filter conditions not working in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to filter on rows where "Condition_2" is true- that much I think is fine. Then trying to get rows where the Tax col is less than Tax_calculated but not working....
[image]

Comment: As part of formulating a valid [mre], please share [code and data as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).  To share dataframes: output of `print(df)` or `print(df.to_dict())`. If df is large, consider printing `df.head()`. Also you are not showing *condition 2*.

Answer (score 0):

The modified code filters the DataFrame 'data' based on two conditions: 'Condition_2' being True and 'Tax_calculated' exceeding 'Tax'. It then selects the columns 'Tax_calculated' and 'Tax' from the filtered data, presenting the resulting DataFrame with the specified columns for further analysis or display.

filtered_data = data[(data['Condition_2'] == True) & (data['Tax_calculated'] > data['Tax'])]

selected_columns = filtered_data[['Tax_calculated', 'Tax']]

Comment: thanks! but why can't i do it in one fell swoop as I was trying to? why do i have to create a filtered df and then only subset on that for this to work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't forget to format your code, using [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). OP has not asked for selecting columns. Do you see this last step as essential? Ideally validate your answer using OP's mre data, once she has posted it as text, as it is requested by SO guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

**Tax** is never greater than **Tax_calculated** in your example, use `>=` instead.

Comment: What? Then nothing should return, instead of rows where they are equal....